# How to rewrite angularjs functions in plain javascript file. I am migrating old angular to html and plain javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS function needs migrate to plain javascript function. There is existing angularjs file code that I need to reuse in plain Javascript file .

Angularjs function-

```
filter("slice", function () {
        return function (arr, start, length) {
                  return (length = start + length), (arr || 
                   []).slice(start, length);};
    });
```

Migrating to plain javascript function

Comment: There is already JS code in it. Just matter how you pass data to it: `length = start + length; (arr || []).slice(start, length);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function slice(arr, start, length) {
    return (arr || []).slice(start, start + length);
}
```

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(slice(arr, 1, 2)); // Output: [2, 3]
```

This will output `[2, 3]`, which are the elements at indices 1 and 2 in the array.